# Factory/Faker not working in Laravel 5.3 DatabaseSeeder

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-seeding

I've moved my code from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3, everything is working fine except when I run my DatabaseSeeder. This was working perfectly in Laravel 5.2, now when I try to run `php artisan db:seed` in 5.3 I get this error when the Seeder uses Faker:

`[BadMethodCallException]
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()`

Everything seems to be installed correctly.

Code example:

```
<?php

use App\Models\Gallery;
use App\Models\GalleryImage;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class GalleryImageTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('gallery_images')->delete();

        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
        $gallery = Gallery::lists('id')->All();

        foreach(range(1, 98) as $index) {
            GalleryImage::create([
                'page_id' => null,
                'gallery_id' => $faker->randomElement($gallery),
                'alt' => 'Image description',
                'large' => '201508183828fh5ntu80ub-or.jpg',
                'medium' => '201508183828fh5ntu80ub-lg.jpg',
                'thumbnail' => '201508183828fh5ntu80ub-th.jpg',
                'order' => 1,
                'cover' => false,
                'visibility' => 'visible',
            ]);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At last i found it out mysql. Need to change `list` to `pluck`

**Example:**

```
$gallery = Gallery::pluck('id')->All();
```